# Docker not able to communicate with internet (docker0 bridge linkdown)

Tags: docker

I was trying to run below command for testing docker connectivity to INTERNET.

```
docker run appropriate/curl https://google.com
```

It doesn't work and says cannot resolve the host. Then I checked the docker0 bridge which is used in this process.

```
xxxx-yy$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1000 
172.26.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.26.0.1 linkdown
```

I also checked in another system where it was working fine and there was no "linkdown".
Could anyone help as why in my system the docker0 status is down (linkdown). I have restarted then reinstalled the docker but with no success.
I also changed the IP range from default to this new one.

The docker is running on a **Ubuntu virtualbox**.

Comment: Try `ping 8.8.8.8` instead of curl, does that make a difference? Trying to understand if you are having NAT problem or if your DNS resolver is misconfigured.

Comment: docker run appropriate/ping xxx combination is not supported by docker.

Comment: Try this.. `docker pull busybox` and `docker run busybox ping 8.8.8.8` does ping work? If so, then you have a misconfigured DNS resolver, if no then its a NAT issue.

Comment: The ping works. But how I misconfigured DNS? I haven't changed anything after installing the docker.

Comment: $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1

Comment: Does this work for you? `docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 --rm appropriate/curl -fsSL https://google.com`

Comment: No. "Could not resolve the host"

Comment: What kind of resolver do you have in the hosts (ubuntu) `/etc/resolv.conf` ? Please add, `nameserver 8.8.8.8` there and try again.

Comment: I added but still the same problem. Not able to resolve the host.

Comment: Does your network block DNS requests to external DNS servers? What is the IP of your internal DNS server? You should use that directly with docker. I also recommend removing dnsmasq since docker can't use the dnsmasq ip address in containers, resulting to the fallback to 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on an AWS Workspaces (kind of like EC2 with a desktop) and networking in docker using the default bridge network does not work. You can see in the `ip` output that the `docker0` bridge has `linkdown` attribute - but that is not actually the problem: it says `linkdown` whenever there are no current docker containers running and attached to the docker bridge.

One workaround is to create a custom Docker network and these custom networks does not seem to have a problem, even when the default network doesn't connect. So something like:

```
docker network create --driver bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 test
```

Then when you run the container, select the custom network:

```
docker run -ti --rm --network test appropriate/curl https://google.com
```

The actual problem is very likely that the default DNS configuration for the default Docker bridge is not correct - for some reason - and you can fix the problem (not actually a fix, more like another more permanent workaround) by setting a fixed DNS server address in the Docker configuration file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. See [this answer for the details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69678498/53538).

Comment: I tried this solution, but while I run the container, this bridge also remains in state DOWN. I wonder if there's a way to view logs to see if there are any warnings or errors with regard to this?

Comment: `journal -u docker.service` should show you the docker log, but the default log level is very tight-lipped. You may want to first increase the log level (see https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/logs/ ) but my experience with getting useful logs out of the docker daemon has been spotty (another reason to prefer podman).

Comment: Thank you, already found the issue which has to do with the default configuration of systemd-networkd on Debian, see my answer. Actually I discovered this through looking at the general system logs, which included systemd-networkd warnings about the bridge device (simply `journalctl -f`).

Answer (score 0):

I was running Debian 11 with systemd-networkd, and this caused an issue where it unexpectedly interfered with the Docker bridge. This led to the Docker bridge remaining in state DOWN, and docker containers consequently having no internet nor local network connection.

In `/etc/systemd/network` any networks that are defined may interfere with the Docker bridge depending on their `[Match]` section. Mine was:

`/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network`:

```
[Match]
Type=ether

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

`Type=ether` matches also the Docker interfaces, and is thus too generic. So I changed it to this:

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

After a docker restart (`systemctl restart docker`) suddenly containers were able to connect to internet.

Note: This is beside any DNS issues, you can check internet connection using the following (use CTRL+C to abort):

```
docker run -it alpine ping 8.8.8.8
```

Note: you also do need to have ipv4 forwarding enabled on your system. The iptables rules that Docker creates depend on this functionality.